# "Too Specific" tag roundup - 2012/01/20 edition

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

The following tags were selected based on the criteria that they are **too specific to provide a meaningful distinction amongst questions** and should be killed or merged.  I've done my best to find merge targets whenever I can.

[wireless-controllers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless-controllers) [wiimote](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiimote) --> [controllers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controllers)

Wiimotes are wireless controllers, and I don't know that having three categories that could potentially contain controller questions is really warranted.

[retro-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retro-gaming) --> [backwards-compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backwards-compatibility)

[backwards-compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backwards-compatibility) already contains [old-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games), and that's supposedly the point of [retro-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retro-gaming) as well.

[lan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lan) --> [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking)

LAN as a tag is kind of ambiguous, and I'm not sure there's enough of a meaningful distinction that someone interested in gaming on a LAN versus network gaming in general.  I'm also kind of torn, since this could just as easily all become "multiplayer" - there are likely few networking questions valid for this site that don't involve multiplayer in some way...

[konami-code](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konami-code) --> [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats)

Cheats is a meta tag, (which might die in a fire sooner or later) but regardless I'm not sure that the Konami code needs a tag all its own.

[hosting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting) [dedicated-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dedicated-server) --> [servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servers)

This is a weird group.  Hosting generally refers to dedicated servers in the gaming world.

[prestige](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prestige) [killstreak-rewards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/killstreak-rewards)

Two game mechanics of the CoD series.  There's a bunch of questions about these mechanics that don't have them, and there's not really a need for them since the CoD game question count is pretty paltry.

Comment: And of the two open konami-code questions, one is how to enter it and one is why entering it isn't working ... they're barely different questions, and I'm not sure there is any other question on topic for the site that would need the tag.

Comment: I think `wiimote` is potentially useful, I could see someone filtering for that.  `wireless-controllers` not so much, I doubt there are many questions that apply generically to all wireless controllers that aren't shopping recs, so I agree that one should be merged.

Comment: Regarding [tag:prestige] and [tag:killstreak-rewards].  Do we not already have [tag:achievements] which those could be filed under?  For [tag:networking] vs [tag:multiplayer] and [tag:LAN].  I could see some arguments for why [tag:networking] and [tag:LAN] may sometimes not refer to [tag:multiplayer] - for example, network-based features of game consoles that are not multiplayer-related.  Also, there may be some reason (or not) to distinguish [tag:LAN] questions from networking questions involving Internet-based multiplayer or features.  Most of those are probably off-topic here though.

Answer (score 1):

> [retro-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retro-gaming) --> [backwards-compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backwards-compatibility)

Um. Not sure what happened to this one, I thought it was already in place. Reinstated.

> [konami-code](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konami-code) --> [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats)

Agreed. Merged.

> [prestige](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prestige) [killstreak-rewards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/killstreak-rewards)

Disagree - 11/13 are not "paltry" (I still sometimes don't get if their problem is being "too large" to cover game tags or being "too small" to not be warranted existance). Non-CoD questions tagged prestige have been retagged.

> [hosting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting) [dedicated-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dedicated-server) --> [servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servers)

Both [dedicated-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dedicated-server) and [servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servers) now point to [hosting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting) (hosting a game is common language for something that would be on topic; configuring a Linux server's firewall e.g. isn't).

---

I suspend judgement on the rest but tentatively disagree.

Comment: re: CoD subtags, Jeff's direction was we shouldn't really have them until the tag's got a ton of questions, which is why I marked them for review.  CoD as a tag/series of tags doesn't really have that many questions, so I thought it questionable that it has subtags - and cross-game subtags at that.

Comment: I mistyped, it's "dedicated-server" and not "dedicated-servers"